# get jolt json key，i hope transform key ,I have the following dataset that I need to transform:

Tags: json, jolt

I don't know how to use jolt's transformations such as `shift`、`default`、`modify-default-beta`.

I have the following JSON value as

**input** :

```json
{
  "report": {
    "q": "1",
    "b": "2"
  }
}
```

that I need to transform to

the **desired output** :

```json
{
  "report": {
    "q": "1",
    "b": "2"
  },
  "q": "1"
}
```

how can i handle it ?

**Edit** : I was actually trying to find a way to replicate，now i found :

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "modify-default-beta",
    "spec": {
      "q": "@(2,report.&)"
    }
  }
]
```

Comment: yes ,The output is what I want

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a **shift** transformation spec like this

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": "&",
      "@(0,report.q)": "q"
    }
  },
  {
   // this spec stands only for sorting to obtain the exact appearance with the desired result
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "report": "&",
      "q": "&"
    }
  }
]
```

where zero in `@(0,report.q)` represents the value taken from the current level

the ***demo*** on the site http://jolt-demo.appspot.com/ is

[image]

or another method would be by using **shift** transformation again :

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "@": "&", // replicate the whole content
        "q": "&"  // replicate only attribute "q" without a node
      }
    }
  }
]
```

Comment: I'm actually trying to find a way to replicate，now i found。
[{
 "operation":"modify-default-beta",
 "spec":{
  "q":"@(2,report.q)"
 }
}]

Comment: Yes, that's another good solution @bertin